# Apache 2.4 does not execute PHP

Tags: php, apache

I have a problem with apache and PHP 5.4 running on a centOS 7 machine.
Apache host have the directory index option:

```
<Directory my/directory>
Options Indexes
</Directory>
```

The directory where apache points to contains a index.php. But when I navigate the browser to the related website, the browser only shows the php code.

I've already checked, if php is activated in http.conf - and it is. The application (zabbix) should work with this version of PHP and all necessary SQL- and PHP-plugins are installed.

No more Google suggestions for this problem - any of you an idea how to solve this?

---

Output of /etc/http/conf.d/php.conf:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php 
</FilesMatch>

AddType text/html .php

DirectoryIndex index.php

#<FilesMatch \.phps$>
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
#</FilesMatch>

php_value session.save_handler "files"
php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session"
```

Comment: Directory is a full filesystem path, that thing is relative and no, Apache has never executed PHP per-se either, fix the directory directive and check for a handler

Comment: Could you show us the `LoadModule` and `SetHandler` code from `httpd.conf` - it's not an issue with *show indexes* but PHP actually being interpreted at all if you're seeing the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Will post the /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf later

Answer (score -1):

Please check below thinks in your httpd config file

```
    LoadFile "D:/wamp/php/libpq.dll"  // Your sepcified path
    LoadModule php5_module "D:/wamp/php/php5apache2_4.dll" // Your sepcified path
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php    // Your sepcified path 
    PHPIniDir "D:/wamp/php" // Your sepcified path
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably installed PHP from the distribution packages. If so, make sure Apache was restarted after that:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

If that does not help, try reinstalling the PHP packages, then restarting Apache.

If that does not help, post the contents of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` here.